# Unramified Extensions of Local Fields and $\mathcal{O}_L / Q^e \otimes_{k} k^{sep}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Suppose I have an extension of number fields $L/K$, and a prime $P$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ splits into $Q^e$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$. Put $k = \mathcal{O}_K / P$ and $k^{sep}$ for the separable closure of $k$.

Now, if $e = 1$, i.e. $P$ is unramified, then $\mathcal{O}_L/Q^e$ a finite étale $k$-algebra. That is equivalent to saying that $\mathcal{O}_L / Q^e \otimes_k k^{sep}$ is reduced, and also equivlalent to saying that $\mathcal{O}_L / Q^e \otimes_k k^{sep}$ decomposes into the product of copies of $k^{sep}$. Further, for those who enjoy Grothendieck's Galois theory, $k^{sep} \text{-alg} (\mathcal{O}_L / Q^e \otimes_k k^{sep}, k^{sep})$ forms a finite continuous $\text{Aut}_k (k^{sep})$-set from which we can recover the $k$-algebra $\mathcal{O}_L / Q^e$.

In general, $e \neq 1$, and $\mathcal{O}_L/Q^e$ is not a finite étale $k$-algebra. However, I would suspect that it isn't just any finite $k$-algebra; it is not reduced, but perhaps something still characterizes it. So, decompose $\mathcal{O}_L/ Q^e \otimes_k k^{sep}$ into the product of finite $k^{sep}$-algebras $A_1, ..., A_r$, such that, if $A_i \cong B \times C$ for finite $k^{sep}$-algebras $B$ and $C$, then either $B \cong 0$ or $C \cong 0$.

My question is, what can we say about $A_i$, if anything? Does it have any nice properties? I would think that, even though it is not reduced, that there is still some class of finite extensions of $k^{sep}$ that it falls into.

Here is an example. Let $K = \mathbb{Q}_p$, and $L = K(\zeta_{p})$. Then $L/K$ is a totally ramified extension of degree $p-1$; The unique nonzero prime $\pi$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has ramification index $p-1$ and inertial degree $1$, so that, in particular, it factors as $\varpi^e$ in $\mathcal{O}_L= \mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p]$. That the maximal ideal $\pi \mathbb{Z}_p$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is ramified is equivalent to saying that $\mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p] / \varpi^{p-1} \mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p]$ is not an étale $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra, which we can see since it has a nilpotent element. Maybe $(\mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p] / \varpi^{p-1} \mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p] ) \otimes \mathbb{F}_p^{sep}$ splits into copies of $\mathbb{F}_p^{sep} [\epsilon] / \epsilon^{p-1} \mathbb{F}_p^{sep} [\epsilon]$. If I'm right, then that's something pretty nice to say about $\mathcal{O}_L / Q^e \mathcal{O}_L \otimes_k k^{sep}$- even though it's not a product of $k^{sep}$'s, its a product of $k^{sep}$'s with nilpotents adjioned. Sorry if the example isn't complete though.

Thanks.